# How is the resulting code of a Binary matrix calculated

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Firstly I would like to sincerely apologize in advance for my lack of mathematical knowledge.

On lecture notes regarding error-correcting codes i saw this section :

> Linear Codes are codes composed of words (noted $c$) that are obtained after a linear transformations of the bits of the initial word (noted $i$).

> Theses codes are caracterized by their matrix $G(k, n)$ (generative matrix ) such as :
> $i . G = c$

> Thus :
> $$\bar{\begin{bmatrix}101\end{bmatrix}}.\bar{
>  \begin{bmatrix}1011\\0101\\1101\end{bmatrix}}
>  =\begin{bmatrix}\bar{0110}\end{bmatrix}$$

I have a lot of trouble with understanding how this answer is obtained..

Comment: You don't understand the last, displayed equation? It's matrix multiplication, with the arithmetic done modulo 2. Do you know how to multiply two matrices? Do you know about arithmetic modulo 2?

Comment: @GerryMyerson im very sorry i do not know how to do modulo 2 arithmetic, i always confuse it with XOR and Mod...

Comment: Mod 2 arithmetic is a breeze. $0+0=1+1=0$; $0+1=1+0=1$; $0\times0=0\times1=1\times0=0$, $1\times1=1$. So, now you understand how they get the answer?

Comment: FYI - I have no idea what the bars over the matrices are supposed to mean, but if you want them to be over the entire matrix rather than a little bar over the center, use `\overline{ ... }`, not `\bar`

Comment: I say, Ice, do you understand how they get the answer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has lost interest.